# How to include .json files in a python package using a pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, package, pyproject.toml

I am trying to package some python software to be installed from a github repo so users can clone the repo and use `pip install .` to install the package, but multiple .json files keep getting ignored.

Although using a setup.py file is more common, it seems the now accepted usage is a pyproject.toml file. My project structure is

```
myproject
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── align
    │   ├── algorithms.py
    │   └── params.json
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── find.py
```

So far my `pyproject.toml` file has

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=68.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "description"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
license = {file = "LICENSE.txt"}
authors = [
{name = "John Doe"}
]
classifiers = [
"Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
]

[project.scripts]
myproject = "src.main:main"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["src", "src.multiply_align"]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
'src' = ['src/*.json']
'src.multiply_align' = ['src/multiply_align/*.json']
```

But when I try to install the project (fresh conda environemnt, cd into the mypackage directory, run pip install .) the json files get ignored such that when I run the code it throws a FileNotFoundError

I have tried making a MANIFEST.in with a `recursive-include` option but that also doesn't seem to work

Is there something special I'm missing to include JSON files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
'src' = ['src/*.json']
```

Means "in the `src` folder, include all jsons in the `src` subfolder", so you're trying to include `src/src/*.json`.

What you want is

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
'src' = ['*.json']
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't understand how the paths were interpreted. Thank you! This worked